# Program freezes, cannot find solution. SDL and C++

Tags: c++, sdl, freeze

I've checked everywhere in my code and I could not find the reason why my program freezes every time I load it. The problem started happening after I included a new AI header, "schoolboy.h". I checked to make sure that attempting to blit an image wasn't the problem, and it wasn't. So, after some testing, I figured that the problem lied in "void schoolboy_action()" within "schoolboy.h". Here is the entire project's code. I spent an hour looking at that section and could not find a solution. I know that the is really long, and that there are some holes in it that I plan on filling, but please bear with me.

Main.cpp

```
#include "schoolboy.h"
#include "include_file.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    variables();

    while (quit == 1)
    {
        while (MARS.alive == 1)
        {
            SDL_WM_SetCaption("Mobile Anihilation Robot System", NULL);
            applysurface(0,0,background,screen);
            MARS_action();
            MARS_bullet_action(1);
            gunshot_explosion_action(1);
            if (create_schoolboy_variable == 1)
            {create_schoolboy(); create_schoolboy_variable = 0;}
            else if (create_schoolboy_variable < 1)
            {create_schoolboy_variable = rand() % 1;};
            schoolboy_action(0,0,0);
            applysurface(MARS.x-25, MARS.y-25, MARS_image, screen);
            SDL_Flip(screen);
            SDL_Delay(1);
        };
    while (MARS.alive == 0)
    {
            SDL_WM_SetCaption("Mobil Anihilation Robot System", NULL);
    };
    };
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
};
```

include_file.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED
#define INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED

#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

/*structs*/

struct instance_struct
{
    int gunshot_explosion;
    int schoolboy_instance;
};
struct MARS_struct
{
int x;
int y;
int alive;
int bullet;
};
struct MARS_bullet_struct
{
int x;
int y;
int direction;
int exist;
int id;
bool operator<(const MARS_bullet_struct & n)const{return this->id<n.id;}
};
struct schoolboy_struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int direction;
    int id;
    int exist;
    int walk_delay;
    int shoot_delay;
    int walked;
    SDL_Rect clip[3];
    bool operator<(const schoolboy_struct&n)const{return this->id<n.id;}
};
struct gunshot_explosion_struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
    int life;
    int exist;
    bool operator<(const gunshot_explosion_struct&n)const{return this->id<n.id;}
};

/*declaring structs*/
MARS_struct MARS;
instance_struct instance_body;
std::map<int, MARS_bullet_struct>MARS_bullet;
std::map<int, schoolboy_struct>schoolboy;
std::map<int, gunshot_explosion_struct>gunshot_explosion;

/*applysurface*/
void applysurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source,clip,destination,&offset);
};

/*declaring global variables*/
int quit;
int create_schoolboy_variable;
SDL_Event event;
SDL_Rect clip[3];
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *gunshot_explosion_image = NULL;
SDL_Surface *MARS_image = NULL;
SDL_Surface *MARS_bullet_image = NULL;
SDL_Surface *schoolboy_image = NULL;

/*giving variables values*/
void variables()
{
    quit = 1;
    MARS.alive = 1;
    MARS.x = 256;
    MARS.y = 256;
    create_schoolboy_variable = 0;

    clip[0].x = 0;
    clip[0].y = 0;
    clip[0].w = 50;
    clip[0].h = 50;
    clip[1].x = 50;
    clip[1].y = 50;
    clip[1].w = 100;
    clip[1].h = 100;
    clip[2].x = 100;
    clip[2].y = 100;
    clip[2].w = 150;
    clip[2].h = 150;
    clip[3].x = 150;
    clip[3].y = 150;
    clip[3].w = 200;
    clip[3].h = 200;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512,512,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    background = IMG_Load("images/background.png");
    gunshot_explosion_image = IMG_Load("images/gunshot_explosion.png");
    MARS_image = IMG_Load("images/MARS.png");
    MARS_bullet_image = IMG_Load("images/MARS_bullet.png");
    schoolboy_image = IMG_Load("images/schoolboy.png");
};

void gunshot_explosion_action(int instance)
{
    while (instance <= instance_body.gunshot_explosion)
    {
        if (gunshot_explosion[instance].exist == 0)
        {
            gunshot_explosion[instance].life = gunshot_explosion[instance].life + 1;
            if (gunshot_explosion[instance].life > 7)
            {gunshot_explosion[instance].exist = 1;};
            applysurface(gunshot_explosion[instance].x-6,gunshot_explosion[instance].y-6,gunshot_explosion_image,screen);
        };
        instance = instance + 1;
    };
};

#endif // INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED
```

MARS.h

```
#ifndef MARS_H_INCLUDED
#define MARS_H_INCLUDED

#include "include_file.h"

/*character functions*/
void MARS_action()
{
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            MARS.alive = 2;
            quit = 0;
        };

        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_a:
                    if(MARS.x > 0){MARS.x = MARS.x - 16;}; break;
                case SDLK_d:
                    if(MARS.x < 512){MARS.x = MARS.x + 16;}; break;
                case SDLK_w:
                    if(MARS.y > 0){MARS.y = MARS.y - 16;}; break;
                case SDLK_s:
                    if(MARS.y < 512){MARS.y = MARS.y + 16;}; break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    MARS.bullet = MARS.bullet + 1;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].direction = 2;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].x = MARS.x-25;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].y = MARS.y;
                    instance_body.gunshot_explosion = instance_body.gunshot_explosion+1;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].x = MARS.x-25;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].y = MARS.y;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    MARS.bullet = MARS.bullet + 1;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].direction = 0;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].x = MARS.x+25;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].y = MARS.y;
                    instance_body.gunshot_explosion = instance_body.gunshot_explosion+1;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].x = MARS.x+25;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].y = MARS.y;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    MARS.bullet = MARS.bullet + 1;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].direction = 1;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].x = MARS.x;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].y = MARS.y-25;
                    instance_body.gunshot_explosion = instance_body.gunshot_explosion+1;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].x = MARS.x;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].y = MARS.y-25;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    MARS.bullet = MARS.bullet + 1;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].direction = 3;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].x = MARS.x;
                    MARS_bullet[MARS.bullet].y = MARS.y+25;
                    instance_body.gunshot_explosion = instance_body.gunshot_explosion+1;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].x = MARS.x;
                    gunshot_explosion[instance_body.gunshot_explosion].y = MARS.y+25;
                    break;
                case SDLK_ESCAPE: quit = 0; MARS.alive = 2; break;
            };
        };
    };
};

void MARS_bullet_action(int instance)
{
    while (instance <= MARS.bullet)
    {
        if (MARS_bullet[instance].exist == 0)
        {
            if (MARS_bullet[instance].direction == 0)
            {MARS_bullet[instance].x = MARS_bullet[instance].x + 5;};
            if (MARS_bullet[instance].direction == 1)
            {MARS_bullet[instance].y = MARS_bullet[instance].y - 5;};
            if (MARS_bullet[instance].direction == 2)
            {MARS_bullet[instance].x = MARS_bullet[instance].x - 5;};
            if (MARS_bullet[instance].direction == 3)
            {MARS_bullet[instance].y = MARS_bullet[instance].y + 5;};
            if (MARS_bullet[instance].x < 0 or MARS_bullet[instance].x > 512 or MARS_bullet[instance].y < 0 or MARS_bullet[instance].y > 512)
            {MARS_bullet[instance].exist = 1;};
    applysurface(MARS_bullet[instance].x-5, MARS_bullet[instance].y-5, MARS_bullet_image, screen);
        };
        instance = instance + 1;
    };
};

#endif // MARS_H_INCLUDED
```

schoolboy.h

```
#ifndef SCHOOLBOY_H_INCLUDED
#define SCHOOLBOY_H_INCLUDED

#include "include_file.h"

void create_schoolboy(int positionx = 0, int positiony = 0)
{
    instance_body.schoolboy_instance = instance_body.schoolboy_instance + 1;
    positionx = rand() % 1;
    positiony = rand() % 1;
    if (positionx == 0 and positiony == 0)
    {
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].x = 0;
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].y = 0;
    };
    if (positionx == 1 and positiony == 0)
    {
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].x = 512;
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].y = 0;
    };
    if (positionx == 0 and positiony == 1)
    {
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].x = 0;
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].y = 512;
    };
    if (positionx == 1 and positiony == 1)
    {
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].x = 512;
        schoolboy[instance_body.schoolboy_instance].y = 512;
    };
};

void schoolboy_action(int instance, int bullet, int first_direction)
{
    while (instance <= instance_body.schoolboy_instance)
    {
        first_direction = rand() % 1;
        if (schoolboy[instance].exist == 0)
        {
            while (bullet <= MARS.bullet)
            {
                if (schoolboy[instance].x-12 >= MARS_bullet[bullet].x and MARS_bullet[bullet].x <= schoolboy[instance].x+12 and schoolboy[instance].y-12 >= MARS_bullet[bullet].y and MARS_bullet[bullet].y <= schoolboy[instance].y+12)
                {
                    schoolboy[instance].exist = 1;
                };
                bullet = bullet + 1;
            };
            if (schoolboy[instance].walk_delay == 0)
            {
                if (first_direction == 0)
                {
                    schoolboy[instance].walked = 0;
                    if (MARS.x > schoolboy[instance].x)
                    {
                        schoolboy[instance].x = schoolboy[instance].x + 16;
                        applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[0]);
                        schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                    }
                    else if (MARS.x < schoolboy[instance].x)
                    {
                        schoolboy[instance].x = schoolboy[instance].x - 16;
                        applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[2]);
                        schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                    };
                    if (schoolboy[instance].walked = 0)
                    {
                        if (MARS.y > schoolboy[instance].y)
                        {
                            schoolboy[instance].y = schoolboy[instance].y+16;
                            applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[3]);
                            schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                        }
                        else if (MARS.y < schoolboy[instance].y)
                        {
                            schoolboy[instance].y = schoolboy[instance].y+16;
                            applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[1]);
                            schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                        };
                    };

                };
                if (first_direction == 1)
                {
                    schoolboy[instance].walked = 0;
                    if (MARS.y > schoolboy[instance].y)
                    {
                        schoolboy[instance].y = schoolboy[instance].y+16;
                        applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[3]);
                        schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                    }
                    else if (MARS.y < schoolboy[instance].y)
                    {
                        schoolboy[instance].y = schoolboy[instance].y+16;
                        applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[1]);
                        schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                    };
                    if (schoolboy[instance].walked = 0)
                    {
                        if (MARS.x > schoolboy[instance].x)
                        {
                            schoolboy[instance].x = schoolboy[instance].x + 16;
                            applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[0]);
                            schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                        }
                        else if (MARS.x < schoolboy[instance].x)
                        {
                            schoolboy[instance].x = schoolboy[instance].x - 16;
                            applysurface(schoolboy[instance].x-25, schoolboy[instance].y-25, schoolboy_image, screen, &clip[2]);
                            schoolboy[instance].walked = 1;
                        };
                    };
                };
                schoolboy[instance].walk_delay = schoolboy[instance].walk_delay + 1;
            }
            else {schoolboy[instance].walk_delay = schoolboy[instance].walk_delay + 1;};
            if (schoolboy[instance].walk_delay == 10){schoolboy[instance].walk_delay = 0;};
        };
    };
    instance = instance + 1;
};

#endif // SCHOOLBOY_H_INCLUDED
```

All of my files are involved with each other, especially schoolboy.h, which is why I put them down. If you find the answer, can you explain why that's so. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please look at arithmetic operators `++` and `+=`. `x = x + 5` takes more effort to read than `x += 5`, and likewise for `x = x + 1` and `++x`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the tip. It would make it more convident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance = instance + 1 line at the end of schoolboy.h looks like it's outside the while loop that relies on it being incremented to eventually end.

Comment: Thanks! I did not catch that! But why would that error cause the program to freeze instead of going into an infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you seeing the program actually do when it 'freezes'? Do you get an error?

Comment: It freezes before SDL_Flip(screen) can be read. So, it's just a blank screen with no color value. There were no compiler warnings regarding to freezing.

Comment: If you look at your main loop, it calls to schoolboy_action (and enters an infinite loop) before the first call to SDL_Flip. It will also only do one poll for events before going into the infinite loop, so it wont be able to respond to (eg) the Escape button to exit. Does this sound like what's happening?

Comment: Yeah, except that the program crashes, regardless of what I do, so I have to use the terminal to close it.